# How to set three items with same width 33.3% in row using css ? Flex or Grid ( it does not matter )

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is all code example ->

https://codepen.io/mihailovic-aleksandar/pen/eYVREwE

What do I need? First I have a problem with margin, negative margin.
I need the to item be full width 33.3%

To solve the negative margins.

I want each item to be exactly 33.3% and to be full length. It's 32% for me at the moment, and if I set it to 33.3%, it's a shortcut to a new line.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 165px;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 32%;
  height: 75px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item"> 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want the elements to be 33% wide, why are you adding margin?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Also post your entire encessary code here not just a little fragment. Questions must be *+self-containing** and not soley relay on external resources as a codepen. A codepen is acceptable as an add-on such for SASS and LESS.

Answer (score 1):

Even a measly `3px` of `margin` will make your flex items wrap to a new line when using `width: 33%`. You can use `width: calc(100%/3)` to make them exactly `33.33%` but you will have to remove the static left and right `margin`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 165px;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: calc(100%/3);
  margin: auto auto .5em auto;
  height: 75px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```

If you want to have spacing you can use `width: calc(100%/3.1)` on `item` with `margin: auto` so they're centered. The `.1` accounts for some spacing. Another option would be to use `width: calc(100%/3 - 6px);` to account for `margin: 3px;`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 165px;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: calc(100%/3 - 6px); /* -6px accounts for margin: 3px; i.e., top + bottom at 3px = 6px */
  margin: 3px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to include the margin (though you should include a gap over a margin), you need to use `calc(33.33% - 6px)` as width

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap :wrap;
    height: 165px;
    width: 100%;
}

.item {
  background: red;
   display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: calc(33.33% - 6px);
  height: 75px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
   <div class="item">2</div>
   <div class="item">3</div>
   <div class="item">4</div>
   <div class="item">5</div>
   <div class="item">6</div>
   <div class="item"> 7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a container for your items and give them `width:33.33%` and set margin to your items.

Here is an example based on your pen :

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap :wrap;
  height: 165px;
  width: 100%;
}
.item-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 75px;
}
.item{  
  width:100%;
  margin: 3px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution. Also technically way to cpmplicated to chaneg the entire HTML-markup. It would be easier to simply change the width value to the correct width or just apply a grid and control the width through the container (`grid-template-columns`)

Comment: @tacoshy I accidentely clicked on post and am currently edditing it. Also, this is an alternative way that can be usefull if you don't want to change 2 lines instead of one if you need to change your margin

Comment: yeah but you change dozen of HTML lines in exchange and create a complicated and unecessary markup to solve this. A good developer would use then CSS-variables in the root selector to apply changes of margins and paddings at the top with just one value that will adjust to the entire page.

Comment: @tacoshy I have a doubt about the weight of css variables and `calc` function compared to my solution but I indeed think your solution is more elegant. I answered that way because I didn't think about making a variable and didn't see it in your answer. Thanks for the advice

Comment: there is no need for a variable in such short and simple CSS. But as example: https://codepen.io/tacoshy/pen/NWygaLg this would help if you have way longer CSS and HTML and want to apply changes more simply. That way you just change the value in the root element and the entire CSS will adept to it.